# how to search in all file using less

Tags: unix, search, less

In less / search for the next pattern and ? search for the previous pattern.

Is there any way to search pattern from the start of the file to the end? (I useually search forward and then backward but i wanted to know if there is more convenient way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the `man less` page, I found that `/@` will search from the first line.

If multiple files are specified, it will search the first line of the first file.

Comment: /@ actually starts searching at the first line of the first file rather than the current file.  It only makes a difference if you specify multiple files on the command line though.  Still, very useful.  Thanks!

Comment: Whoops!   Fixing.

Comment: very helpfull!
thx!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a way within `less` to always start searches at the beginning of a file, but you can always jump to the beginning of the file by pressing `1g` then perform your search.